# Shriveled scales on arms and stomach?

Tags: skin-condition, bearded-dragon

My beardie has had a few shriveled up looking scales on his stomach for a little while, at first it was just one or two but now there are significantly more, and they've spread to his arms too. I'm not sure if they're tender or not, he doesn't usually like having his legs brush when bathing (I use a soft bristled toothbrush) but it seemed like he was jerking back more this time than usual.

Any idea what this is or if it's something to be worried about? [image][image]

Comment: Can you give me more details and pics.
Tank size and make (glass or mesh),

Substrate,

Temperatures of hot and cold side,

Humidity %,

UV lighting - coil, tube or MVB (last time it was changed),

Feeding schedule, what they are feeding, any vit/min additives with frequency.

Comment: 40gal right now, glass tank with mesh top and reptile carpet. The temperature on the warm side is around 99-110 and the cool side stays around 80. My humidity is too high right now because we've had a lot of rain. He eats black solder fly larva dubia roaches and meal worms for protein, those are fed every two to three days depending on if he is willing to eat or not. For veg he gets a combination of collared or mustard greens, bell peppers, yellow squash, green beans, black berries, and turnips. Greens are offered everyday and he usually eats them.

Comment: His UV light is a tube light that was put in around 2 months ago. I dust with fluker's repta calcium and repti cal hertivite with beta carotene twice a week.

Comment: It seems it's some kind of fungus or bacteria. You should take it to the vet, especially because you took it a bath and nothing's happened. I'm not so familiar with this species though, so I'd love it to see someone give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I where you I would take him to a vet. I have never heard about anything like this with bearded dragons before. I have one of my own and nothing like this has happened. But mine is just one of millions. I hope he gets better soon. If it continues to spread I really urge you to take him to a reptile vet. They should have a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

My beardie has had the same thing for a little over 2 years. These brown dried scales are typically caused from dragging them the opposite way that they go. Notice how when you pick the beardie up his belly snags on clothing and things? The scales tend to tear off little at a time causing tenderness and drying/scabbing. This causes a bit of discomfort but goes away eventually if you continue to bath them in warm water.